# libgdx: how do you position a 3d model instance with Othographic Camera?

Tags: libgdx

I have a Screen class that uses Othographic Camera and want to put a 3d model on it.

```
@Override
    public void show() {

    ....
    mCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    mCamera.setToOrtho(false, width * sclWidth, height * sclWidth);
    ....

    //3d instance initialization
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        model = modelBuilder.createBox(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)), VertexAttributes.Usage.Position| VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);

  modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model, 128,128,128);
  modelInstance.transform.set(mCamera.invProjectionView);
}



@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(63 / 255f, 128 / 255f, 70 / 255f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //mCamera.rotateAround(Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(0,1,0),1f);
        mCamera.update();
    mBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mCamera.combined);

    mBatch.begin();
    mBatch.draw(img, 128*10, 0);

    mBatch.end();

    modelBatch.begin(mCamera);

    modelBatch.render(modelInstance);

    modelBatch.end();

}
```

It is in 2d view and I can put any 2d sprite with x and y on the screen according to the screen width and height.

However when doing 3d models, it is completely different.

The 3d model is stretched according to the camera screen and rendered in the center of the screen. I couldn't find the 3d model setX or setY/SetZ functions.

How should the 3d model be positioned and what functions should I use? Any advice or direction to tutorials will be thankful.

update:
camera position: (768.0,192.0,0.0)
Camera projection: [0.0012019231|0.0|0.0|-0.0]
[0.0|0.0021378205|0.0|-0.0]
[0.0|0.0|-0.02|-1.0]
[0.0|0.0|0.0|1.0]

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Quick-start

Comment: yeah i went through most part of it but still not being able to understand. I thought when we set the Orthographic Camera with screen width and height, it will map to each pixel of the screen. But when putting the 3d box with 0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f, it is showing me a big stretched box that is around 300pixel wide. and I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you instantiated your model instance at coordinates 128, 128, 128. I'm not sure where you have your camera positioned, but if you want a centered object, the X and Y of the model instance should match those of the camera position.

Also, if you want the entire model to be visible, you need to move it away in the Z direction. The camera looks down the -Z axis, so a model instance's position's Z must be less than the Z position of the camera to be visible.

Your main issue is this line, which should be removed:

```
modelInstance.transform.set(mCamera.invProjectionView);
```

You definitely do not want to apply the camera's projection matrix and use it as the model's transform matrix.

A vertex position is typically (as in ModelBatch's default shader) mapped from world coordinates to screen coordinates by multiplying its position by a series of matrices. The **transform matrix** describes the ModelInstance's position, rotation, and scale, so it translates the original model's vertex positions into world space. The **view matrix** then translates the vertex to it's camera-relative location (camera space, aka view space). And then the **projection matrix** translates the vertex to screen space (projects it to the rectangular screen). Since the view and projection matrices are both defined by the camera, the can be pre-multiplied and passed to the batch all at once (`camera.combined`).

In the shader, each vertex position is multiplied by the matrices to get it into screen space.

So to move a model instance around in the world, you perform actions on its transform matrix, such as `modelInstance.transform.translate(x,y,z)`. You generally should never need to call `set` on it. The line `modelBatch.begin(mCamera);` takes care of the `camera.combined` matrix for you under the hood.

When working with SpriteBatch in 2D, you are placing sprites directly in world space, since there is no source Model with defined vertex positions. This is why there is normally no need to use a transform matrix when using SpriteBatch (although it can be used to move the entire plane of sprites into some place in 3D world space).

Comment: wow, thanks alot. I figured out without using modelInstance.transform.set(mCamera.invProjectionView);. Setting the x and y value of the camera gave me big hint on how to do this. Again, thanks!

Comment: and btw. do you know what this is doing? I am trying to figure out why the circle doesn't stop. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118804/libgdx-and-gdx-ai-how-to-implement-wander-behavior

Comment: Haven't used gdx.ai, sorry.